# How to make HDIV work with <spring:bind> tag?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, hdiv

I have a scenario where I need to html tag instead of spring form tag using the spring:bind. However, HDIV does not seem to store this parameter in state to evaluate it later. 
Ex:

In the BindTag class of springframework, I don't see the invocation of RequestDataValueProcessor like, say InputTag ().
Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0):

I found nothing in the document or sample code that gives a demo that HDIV will work with spring:bind. Why don't you use the form tags?

Comment: I am using form:tags in some places. However, in a particular case, I have to use a button tag and a btn-toggle type. there is nothing equivalent in spring mvc. Spring form:button tag makes the type as submit.